# Should I store player information on server or client?

Tags: python, sockets, multiplayer

I'm making a multilayer, text-based game in python sockets. The game is two player with a server which the clients connect to. I'm not sure whether to store player information (name, health, etc) on the server or on the client? What are the advantages of both? I was thinking about storing the information on the client and sending the player object to the server when ever it changes, though this probably isn't very efficient. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think the problem with this question is that it is not programming specific. It just asks which method is better, but it has nothing to do with a programming problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you shouldn't even consider storing data like health client-side. Doing that will allow super-easy hacks to be made and the fact that the game is written in Python makes this a lot easier.

So I think you should keep these data in the server-side and use it from there.